# Access Denied/401 error when running clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

Tags: iis, sharepoint

I'm creating an MVC app that requires me to nab the group users from a Sharepoint site. I'm getting a 401 error when I publish and run it via IIS (localhost). When I run it through the debugger though, everything works as intended.

I'm assuming it's a permissions error based on the context. Is there a way to run the app normally using my current NTLM credentials programmatically (instead of what seems like the IIS account/user)?

**Code**
(I'm on mobile right now, so I'm sorry if anything looks wonky...)

```
// Constructor
clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepointsite");
clientContext.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
//clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredentials("username", "password", "domain"); <- this works just fine if I hard code my current credentials

// Calling method
UserCollection users = GetUsersCollection();
clientContext.Load(users);
try {
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // 401 error here
    return true;
}
catch {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the credentials you connect to SharePoint with CSOM it would look something like this:

`clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");`

You can do MVC impersonation like this:

```
        string currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
        impersonationContext =
            ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate();
        currentUser += "Impersonate:" + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        impersonationContext.Undo();
        ViewBag.U = currentUser;
        return View();
```

I found that example in this thread:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1961337.aspx?Asp+Net+MVC+5+how+to+impersonate+user+on+IIS

Comment: I only have access to the username (and probably the domain) and I'm trying to use Windows Authentication for this app. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: You can try using this:  NetworkCredential cred = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;  That should give you the current logged in users credentials.

Comment: I've tried that, and unfortunately it still gives me a 401 error.

Comment: Can you post more of your source code in the question and are you certain its not a case of access being properly denied to the account in question? If you are setting the context credentials = to the current users creds it should throw an exception because it cannot retrieve the credentials or the authentication should work normally.

Comment: I've updated the post. The new NetworkCredentials line works if I hard code my own current credentials in, but when I use the Default line, it's denying me.

Comment: This is really more of an IIS issue than it is a CSOM which I am not as strong with.  I have been looking into it though and do you have ASP.NET Impersonation enabled for the site you are running the code from?  I believe if that is working correctly you should remove the lines of code about the credentials.

Comment: I tried enabling impersonation in my Web.config file yesterday but I got a 500.24 error so I went back and disabled it.

Comment: You can try the thread I posted above and that code example or you will have to re-enable the impersonation and troubleshoot the 500 error.  IIS code has certain limitations that cannot be circumvented.

Comment: The impersonation string is returning the correct user name. But I'm still getting a 401 error and I can access the SharePoint site normally via browser and through debug. :( Does it have to do anything with dying the credentials for clientContext?

Comment: Why not run the application as a service account and use the username to filter the data you need.  Otherwise I think its just a question of getting impersonation working correctly to run it as that user.  You cannot create a NetworkCredential from a WindowsIdentity:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284017/how-to-convert-windowsidentity-to-a-networkcredential